# Parsing Google Analytics API Python json response into python dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Trying to parse Google Analytics API Python json response into python dataframe, and then ETL to MS SQL Server using python.

I get a successful output called feed
    import json, gdata

```
data_query = gdata.analytics.client.DataFeedQuery({
'ids': 'ga:67981229',
'dimensions': 'ga:userType,ga:sessionCount,ga:source', ##ga:source,ga:medium
'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
##'filters': 'ga:pagePath==/my_url_comes_here/',
##'segment':'',
'start-date': '2015-01-01',
'end-date': '2015-01-03',
'prettyprint': 'true',
'output':'json',
})
feed = my_client.GetDataFeed(data_query)
```

However, when I try to parse the the data using this code it doesn't work and I get the below error

> > > response = json.parse(feed) ## I also tried json.load(feed) and json.loads(feed)
> > >
> > > data = json.parse(feed)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           data = json.parse(feed)
> > >       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
> > >
> > > data = json.loads(feed)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           data = json.loads(feed)
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 338, in loads
> > >           return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
> > >           obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> > >       TypeError: expected string or buffer
> > >
> > > data = json.load(feed)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           data = json.load(feed)
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 286, in load
> > >           return loads(fp.read(),
> > >       AttributeError: 'DataFeed' object has no attribute 'read'
> > >       And I have already imported all of json as seen at the top, furthermore - my end objective is to ETL this to MS SQL Server - so any help on effective method to do this with a JSON Python object would help a LOT!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the json response manually into a dataframe you could try using the Pandas library which has built in [methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/remote_data.html#remote-data-ga) to query the Google Analytics API. Once you get your Google Analytics Metrics into a dataframe, you could insert records into SQL Server using the [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) method.